# Target menu item - CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to target the light grey color that appears in the background of the menu items on this site (where I have placed the red dots). I can't seem to target the correct element in order to remove the grey color - can anyone help me with this? http://226.f2e.myftpupload.com

Thanks

[Screenshot of menu](http://226.f2e.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/stack-menu-css.jpg)

[image]

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a link to your web site which will change and help no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: Most modern browsers ship with some sort of DevTools. In Chrome you can right click on either of the grey elements and select "inspect element". This will show you what parts of the stylesheet is applied to that specific element.

In your case it seems the color is applied when you hover on the "Products" menu button. `header nav.main_menu ul li:hover a span:not(.plus), header nav.main_menu ul li.active a span:not(.plus) { background-color: rgba(243, 243, 241, 1); }`

Hope this points you in the right direction. If you need a more detailed answer, please write a more detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the css selector

```
.ubermenu-target-text
```